# Validate TextField array in javaFX

Tags: javafx

In my program I have a plus and minus button that increase or decrease the number of textfields. Now what I want to do is to open a new panel after all fields are filled. The problem that I'm having is that if I fill even only one of the textfields and click the verify button, it goes to the next panel even if the other textfields are empty.

```
    stage = primaryStage;

    pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background: #CEF6D8;");

    centerPane1 = new Pane();

    GridPane mainGrid = new GridPane();
    mainGrid.setPadding(new Insets(150, 0, 0, 100));
    mainGrid.setVgap(50);

    // ADULTS, CHILDREN AND INFANT GRID
    noPassGrid = new GridPane();
    noPassGrid.setHgap(10);

    plus = new Button("+");
    plus.setMinWidth(50);
    plus.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(plus, 1, 0);

    plus.setOnAction(e -> {
        plus(count);
        getArraySize();
    });

    count = new Label("1");
    count.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(count, 2, 0);

    minus = new Button("-");
    minus.setMinWidth(50);
    minus.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(minus, 3, 0);

    minus.setOnAction(e -> {
        minus(count);
            getArraySize();
    });


    noPassGrid.getChildren().addAll(plus, count, minus);

    GridPane.setConstraints(noPassGrid, 0, 2);

    mainGrid.getChildren().addAll(noPassGrid);


    search = new Button("SEARCH");
    search.setPrefSize(300, 100);
    search.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 30));
    grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(150, 0, 0, 450));
    grid.setVgap(20);
    grid.setHgap(20);

    test = new Label();
    test.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    test.setLayoutX(500);
    test.setLayoutX(100);



    search.setOnAction(e -> {

        for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
            passName[i] = new TextField();
            passName[i].setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
            passName[i].setPromptText("Enter Name");
            GridPane.setConstraints(passName[i], 2, i);

            grid.getChildren().addAll(passName[i]);
        }
    });

    verify = new Button("VERIFY");
    verify.setPrefSize(300, 100);
    verify.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 30));

    verify.setOnAction(e -> {
        for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
            if(passName[i].getText().equals("")) {
                test.setText("INCORRECT");
            }
            else {
                center2 = new Pane();
                pane.setCenter(center2);
            }
        }
    });


    centerPane1.getChildren().addAll(mainGrid, grid, test);
    pane.setCenter(centerPane1);

    bottom1 = new AnchorPane(verify, search);
    bottom1.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 100, 0));
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(search, 150.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(verify, 150.0);
    pane.setBottom(bottom1);

    scene = new Scene(pane, 1200, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}


public void getArraySize() {
    arrayLength = counter;
    passName = new TextField[arrayLength];
}

public void plus(Label l) {
    if(counter < 8) {
        counter++;
        l.setText("" + counter);
    }
}

public void minus(Label l) {
    if(counter > 1) {
        counter--;
        l.setText("" + counter);
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Do you want the verify button to work only if all the textfields are filled?

Comment: If the textFields are empty I want to show the message. When they are all filled I want to open a new panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the logic of the verify button, your button will make the pane appear if at least one of the textfields is filled, on the other hand you want to make the pane appear only if all the textfields are filled so you should do something like this:

```
verify.setOnAction(e -> {
    boolean valid = true; // Variable to store whether the inputs are filled
    for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        if(passName[i].getText().equals("")) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if(valid) {
        center2 = new Pane();
        pane.setCenter(center2);
    } else {
        test.setText("INCORRECT");
    }
});
```